# How much training data do I need for a CNN that recognizes the vocalizations of a single person?

Tags: conv-neural-network

I have a friend that communicates through unique vocalizations (not in any language), and I want to build a CNN that can recognize these sounds.  I know that for speech recognition to generalize to many people, a lot of training data is necessary.  However, for a CNN that recognizes audio for a single person, can anyone guess at how many samples I would need for each vocalization (supposing I might need to distinguish between about 20 sounds)?  Any help would be appreciated.