# CNN for audio recognition has near perfect test and validation accuracy but not generalizing to new data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am creating a CNN to recognize a friend's speech.  She uses unique vocalizations (not in any language) to communicate.  To begin, I recorded 60 samples of three of these sounds (180 .wav samples total).  After training the model, I was getting near perfect accuracy from both the test and validation data. I then recorded new sounds immediately after this training, and was getting about 50 percent accuracy, which showed some level of learning and generalizing, since random guesses on 3 classes should have been getting about 33% accuracy.

The next day I tried recording new audio again, and the model's predictions were as good as random.  My guess as to the problem is that the model is sensitive to very small changes in environment.  It showed some learning immediately after training because the environment would have been very similar.  However, the following day, there were probably more substantial changes to environment (background noise, distance from microphone, sitting in different part of the room, etc.).  Does this seem like a reasonable guess as to the cause of the problem?  And if so, how can I make my model less sensitive to environment?  Would adding white noise help?  Are there ways to add background noise to my samples?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That is to be expected! 180 samples is not nearly enough to train the CNN on. A CNN contains thousands up to millions of parameters so you could quite possibly have many more parameters to tune than bytes of data in your dataset!

Futhermore, your claim of getting perfect accuracy on the test set seem suspicious. I'd wager that you have accidentally used test data to train the model with.

You could try "growing" your dataset by adding randomized noise to the sound files. I don't think that would help much though. The network would become resilient to the type of white noise you added, but probably not to the type of noise found in actual recordings. For example, in speech recognition noises people make when speaking like breathing, saying "uh" and "eh", or clearing their throats, can confuse the recognizer. It is very hard to synthetically add such noises.

Also, while two sounds may sound similar to human ears, their waveforms might be completely different. A song played in different keys sound similar or even identical to human ears but have totally different waveforms. You have the same effect if you listen to someone talking indoors vs. outdoors vs. in a noisy bar. Even whether someone is standing or sitting can completely change the sound of their voice.

Bottom line: you need waaaay more data. I also recommend experimenting with RNNs and Bidirectional RNNs. They are a better fit for temporal data like sound samples than CNNs. Generally they also require less parameters so training is faster.

Comment: Yes, I thought I was using way too little data.  I also tested the model with speech data provided by Google, using about 1000 samples per word, and it worked well.  I was hoping I could get away with less data, since it only needs to recognize one person. I was surprised at how well it did with only 60 samples.  I will review my code and see if I incorrectly implemented train_test_split.  Do you have an idea for how many samples are necessary? [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57024752/how-much-training-data-do-i-need-for-a-cnn-that-recognizes-the-vocalizations-of)

Comment: I checked my training, validation and test split, and the sets were all distinct.  So why would I be getting such good accuracy?  It's all one person saying the same thing 60 times in a similar manner, so I suspect the data is just really similar.  Also, I've come across articles online where people have managed to get decent CNN performance with small data sets.  I do think you're right about needing more data; however, I was just surprised to get such good numbers for 180 samples.